# Upload file to Flask Python 3 server from url

Tags: python, server

I want to download some files to my server's storage from URL. For example, you have [url](https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/composite/1599064200/24000/2/0_1.png) and want to save it. I've found only examples for downloading from the user's computer and it doesn't work in my case.
I used code below to download files in my local programs

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

but when running on server it produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/DenShlk/mysite/flask_app.py", line 26, in hello_world
    save_pic_by_id(id)
  File "/home/DenShlk/mysite/flask_app.py", line 20, in save_pic_by_id
    with urllib.request.urlopen(pic_url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the real problem. I used [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com) and there is the white list of sites that can be accessed from free account.